# Excel - VBA: WorksheetFunction and variable in one formula

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I have the below VBA code in Excel but i keep getting the following error: `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch.`

Here is the code,

```
Dim ssw
Dim ave
Dim mdq
Dim rec

ssw = Cells(2, 2).Value
mdq = Cells(3, 2).Value

Sheets("Sum").Select

rec = WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(500000, 1)))

For i = 2 To rec + 1
    ave = WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(rec + 1, 1)), Cells(i, 1).Value, Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(rec + 1, 7)))
    Cells(i, 9).Value = ave * ssw
Next i
```

From what i can see, i can't multiply a variable with a worksheet function, like in my code. Can i in some way transform the worksheet function result or the variable `ssw` so that i can multiply the two. I also looked at putting the actual formula in the cells, but i don't really want that.

Comment: On which line do you get the error??

Comment: In addition to answering Gary's question, please post a sample of your data.  Your code runs without error for me, if I enter random data into the cells you reference.

Answer (score 0):

I DONT KNOW WHY YOU ADDED rec + 1 may be this is the reason you getting error.
TRY THIS

```
Dim ssw
Dim ave
Dim mdq
Dim rec

ssw = Cells(2, 2).Value
mdq = Cells(3, 2).Value

Sheets("Sum").Select

rec = WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(500000, 1)))

For i = 2 To rec 
    ave = WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(rec , 1)), Cells(i, 1).Value, Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(rec, 7)))
    Cells(i, 9).Value = ave * ssw
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. The code i have is for a button on a sheet called Inputs, while the results gets placed in another sheet called Sum. When i tested the code i ran/debugged it from the VBA IDE and it gave me the error, but when I went to the input sheet and press the button, it works fine. But what i did do, is put `Sheets("Inputs").Select` in my code just after the variables. The code now looks like this,

```
Dim ssw
Dim ave
Dim mdq
Dim rec

Sheets("Inputs").Select

ssw = Cells(2, 2).Value 'These two cells are from the Inputs sheet
mdq = Cells(3, 2).Value

Sheets("Sum").Select

' From here all the cells refer to the Sum sheet

rec = WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(500000, 1)))

For i = 2 To rec + 1
    ave = WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(rec + 1, 1)), Cells(i, 1).Value, Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(rec + 1, 7)))
    Cells(i, 9).Value = ave * ssw
Next i
```